problem in printing a word with all its substrings, sorted by length in python
Here is the code:
a = input("Write a word: ")

substrings = []

for begin in range(len(a)):
    for end in range(begin + 1, len(a) + 1):
        substrings.append(a[begin:end])
substrings.sort(key=len)

for member in substrings:
    print(member)

I don't understand this line:
for end in range(begin + 1, len(a) + 1):

Why should I add one to len(a)?

begin goes from 0 to len(a); so end must go from 1 to len(a) + 1. The slice [0:0] is an empty string, so the range of end values must be offset by one so as to cover the whole string.

The result of range() doesn't include the final number, so if you use len(a) in the second range, the last value will be len(a)-1.
Similarly, slices don't include the element with the last index. So none of the substrings will include the last character of the input string.
So you either have to use len(a)+1 in the range, or use end+1 in the slice. If you do the latter, you need to change the range to range(begin, len(a)) so you don't skip the first character in the range.

You need to add 1 to len(a) here:
for end in range(begin + 1, len(a) + 1):

because you need to include the last character of a.
By the same token, this:
print(list(range(2)))

prints: [0, 1], not [0, 1, 2].
See also:

How slicing in Python works

